# Can I connect my Linux PC to the Internet with a Nokia E71?

Tags: linux, modem, tethering

Can I connect my Linux PC to the Internet with a Nokia E71?

I've looked for answers elsewhere but everything I've found refers to file synchronization, sending SMSs, playing with the address book, etc. I just want the Internet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to search for the right terms :)

What you're trying to do is called "tethering", and it seems to be [possible with the E71](http://troyready.com/blog/?p=194).

Comment: Perfect, thanks! (Can't test it now as it's not my phone, but will report back:)

Comment: link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

For usb/bluetooth tethering I tried with wvdial like in [this example](http://ivanz.com/2008/09/18/nokia-e71-as-a-usb-or-bluetooth-3g-data-modem-on-linux/) but cannot do right.

For a wi-fi hotspot there is JoikuSpot Premium (and set encryption to WEP Open to set a password, or WEP Shared; I cannot set a password at the Light version and it didn't work, only at the Premium version was ok), search on google for "joikuspot premium app".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).